# Using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) from Sublime Text

Tags: linux, windows, bash, sublimetext, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wanted to use `gcc`, `g++` and `make` from Sublime Text to be able to compile C and C++ code to Linux runnables on Windows. I couldn't run `bash.exe` from Sublime Text, as many other users on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You have to copy the `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` file to the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` directory.
   Required because of the [WoW64 file system redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) (Thanks [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455673/using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-from-sublime-text#comment68516907_40458143)!)
2. Then you have to create a new build system in the Sublime Text with the following code. (`Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...`)

   ```
   {
     "cmd" : ["bash", "-c", "gcc ${file_name} -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}"],
     "shell": true,
     "working_dir": "${file_path}",
   }
   ```

   This code will complile the .c code and than run it. The output will be shown in the Sublime's Build Results panel.
3. When you want to use this Build System, select it in the `Tools -> Build System` list, then hit `Ctrl + B`.

You can customize the command I put there, the main thing is that you can run Linux commands using `bash -c "CommandsYouWantToRun"`

Comment: Is the first step necessary when using 32-bit Sublime Text on 64-bit Windows? I had a similar question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/1140014/how-to-launch-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-from-third-party-application), that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, I think. I use a 32-bit Sublime Text too, and this was what worked for me.

Comment: As an additional note: step #1 is required because of the [WoW64 filesystem redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I added a note based on what you said. Thanks for that information.

Comment: I don't like the idea of copying files to a Windows system directory. Couldn't you simply use an absolute path, e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\bash`?

Comment: I think it should work. Unfortunately I cannot try it for you at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, says that CMD doesn't accept UNC paths (the working dir is \\wsl$\etc).

Answer (score 3):

In WSL2, the best possible way according to me is using the below sublime-build file.

- You have to create a new build system in the Sublime Text with the following code. 
  (`Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...`)

```
    {
    "shell_cmd": "ubuntu run \"g++ `wslpath '${file}'` && ./a.out<inp.in>out.in \" ",
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir":"$file_path",
    "selector":"$file_name"
    }
```

- This code will complile the .cpp code and use inp.in and out.in as input and output files respectively (`Optional, if you don't want that, then replace ./a.out<inp.in>out.in with ./a.out`). The output will be shown in the Sublime's Build Results panel.
- When you want to use this Build System, select it in the `Tools -> Build System` list, then hit `Ctrl + B`.

Comment: Can this use a working path within the WSL file system? When I run my file I get an error related to the address (\\wsl$\Ubuntu etc)

Answer (score 1):

On WSL 2 the suggested solution doesn't work. Here is a solution to execute on a WSL 2 target a script edited in Sublime Text on Windows. Create a `bash-wsl.sublime-build` file:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "bash -c \"wslpath '${file}'\" | bash -s",
    "shell": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This MS dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/) recommends `wsl` as the default way for invoking WSL command line calls from Windows. So, in principle your sublime build config should look like this:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "wsl -- <your-linux-build-command>",
    "shell": true,
}
```

One caveat is the correct way of converting Windows paths to Linux style, which requires `wslpath` to be invoked as a sub-command in your call. E.g.:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "wsl -- cmake --build \\$(wslpath '$project_path\\build')",
    "shell": true,
}
```

Mind that you need two `\` to avoid sublime's variable replacement.

This works (at least for me) for WSL 1 and 2 alike.